# How to cut string with Regex and Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to use Notepad++ to cut the string in the text file using regex.

I have this type of strings: `"<a href="/groups/1122some_text_here/sometexthere"AnotherText`

I need to replace it with: `"<a href="/groups/1122/"AnotherText`

I need to keep only numbers and close it with slash.

I could get all entries with `/groups/[\d].*` regex.

[image]

How to replace it in a right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following replacement:

```
 Find What:   (?<=/groups/)(\d+).*?"
 Replacement:  $1/>
```

[image]

Or, perhaps, adding the closing angle bracket:

```
Find:    (?<=/groups/)(\d+).*?"
Replace: $1/">
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks. I have "<a href="/groups/1122some_text_here/sometexthere"Anothertext <-here. I have to keep Anothertext. So I have to search until " only.